# List iterators not compatible

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have this for:

```
for (list<Docente>::iterator it3 = ((*it2).getDocentes()).begin(); it3 != ((*it2).getDocentes()).end(); it3++)
```

This ((*it2).getDocentes) returns a list  of Docentes. So why does it say that list iterators are incompatible? Any help?

Method getDocentes() :

```
list <Docente> getDocentes() const;
list <Docente> EdicaoDisciplina :: getDocentes() const
{
    return docentes;
}
```

Error:

Expression: list iterators incompatible

Comment: When does it say it? At run-time?

Comment: Please show code for `it2` and `getDocentes`, as well as the exact error message.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't provided enough information.

If you get that typical MS Visual C++ run-time assertion about incompatible iterators, then I suspect that your `getDocentes()` returns the list *by value*, i.e. it returns a temporary copy of the original container. That means that `begin()` is called on one temporary copy and `end()` is called on a completely different temporary copy. That makes the iterators returned by `begin()` and `end()` incompatible, since it is illegal to compare iterators that point into different containers. Debug versions of some run-time libraries can catch such errors and issue run-timer assertion failures.

It is also possible that the same problem happens even earlier, because of `*it2` returning its result *by value*.

**EDIT:** Just as I guessed, your `getDocentes()` returns its result by value. This is virtually meaningless and catastrophically inefficient. Such heavy objects as lists are not supposed to be passed around by value. Return it by reference

```
const list <Docente>& EdicaoDisciplina :: getDocentes() const
{
    return docentes;
}
```

Now you have to use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator` (and lose all these excessive pairs of `()`)

```
for (list<Docente>::const_iterator it3 = it2->getDocentes().begin(); 
     it3 != it2->getDocentes().end(); 
     ++it3)
  ...
```

Finally, evaluating `it2->getDocentes().end()` on every iteration is not a good idea either

```
for (list<Docente>::const_iterator 
       it3 = it2->getDocentes().begin(),
       it3_end = it2->getDocentes().end(); 
     it3 != it3_end; 
     ++it3)
  ...
```

Comment: But then the for cycle is incorrect since I have iterator by one side and const iterator by the other.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed iterator it3, to const_iterator. Everything works now. Thanks man. +1 for the help.

Comment: @André: Where? How? If your `getDocentes()` returns a const-qualified object, the both `begin()` and `end()` will produce a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Yeah but then the iterator it3 will have to be a const_iterator. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Well, yes, this is why I said "Now you have to use `const_iterator`...".

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call getDocentes() you're getting back a new list, and you can't validly compare iterators across different STL containers.

In your case, there is a list that gets returned when you call getDocentes().begin(), and then there is a new list created for every loop iteration, when you call getDocentes().end().

You could either use a range-based for loop, if you have C++11, or you could just cache the begin and end iterators before entering you for loop:

```
list <Docente> myDocentes(getDocentes());
list <Docente>::iterator begin = myDocentes.begin();
list <Docente>::iterator end = myDocentes.end();

for(list<Docente>::iterator i = begin; i != end; i++) { .... }
```

Or, just use the range based for:

```
for(auto &it : getDocentes()) { ... }
```